# initialized vs uninitialized delegates. Which one to use

Tags: c#, wpf, delegates

I have Come across two different but very similar approaches when a delegate is to be invoked, but I have not been able to find any argument of when to use one over the other.

for this ill show both ways implementing The INotifyPropertyChanged.

The First makes sure check if PropertyChanged aint null:

```
class Foo_One : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void OnPropertyChanged(string propname)
    {
        if(PropertyChanged!=null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propname));
    }
}
```

The second way do not bother checking if PropertyChanged is null cause it makes sure it newer can be.

```
class Foo_Two : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged= delegate{};
    void OnPropertyChanged(string propname)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propname));
    }
}
```

Here I am just guessing...

if PropertyChanged can be null it it will not reserve the space for it in memory until used, However with the INotifyPropertyChanged used on a ViewModel object will always initialize the PropertyChanged and therefore making the Foo_Two a better implementation in this case?

so for any other delegate which have "optional use" such as one of the many eventHandlers existing in the .net UIElement class, Foo_one would in this type of situation be better to minimize Memory use?

Is my guessing completly of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your explanation is very close, except for one thing: this trick is not about memory consumption, because `delegate{}` objects take negligible amount of space. It is not about CPU cycles either, because executing an empty delegate takes very little time.

The trick is about readability and maintainability of the code, because it trades an initialization in a single place in code for the `if(Xyz!=null)` conditions in all places where you use the delegate. This trade pays off when there is only one spot where you use the delegate; adding a second use brings you pure savings. That is why your second approach is a good implementation choice.

Comment: Thank you for very much for clarifying